# dynamic_pointer_cast from base to derived

Tags: c++

I'm having issues with `std::dynamic_pointer_cast`

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base() { }
    virtual ~Base() { }
};


class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived(int Data) : m_data(Data) { }
    virtual ~Derived() { }

    int GetData() { return m_data; }

private:
    int m_data;
};
```

I'm then trying to do this:

```
Derived d(42);

std::shared_ptr<Base> BasePtr = std::make_shared<Base>(d);

// DerivedPtr is nullptr here.
std::shared_ptr<Derived> DerivedPtr = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived>(BasePtr);

std::cout << DerivedPtr->GetData();
```

Is it possible cast from a base to a derived class so that the above code would print `5`? With the base pointer being constructed from a `Derived` object via `std::make_shared`

Comment: Actually, does calling `std::make_shared<Base>` only construct a `Base`, not a `Derived`?

Comment: no, it is not possible

Comment: Your `dynamic_cast` fails that's why you're getting `nullptr`. Consequently, you cant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call

```
std::make_shared<Derived>(d);
```

so that it will create Derived object. Then dynamic cast would not fail

Answer (score 1):

```
std::shared_ptr<Base> BasePtr = std::make_shared<Base>(d);
```

is copy constructing a `Base` from `d`. So the dynamic cast will fail.

A direct route to your intended `BasePtr` pointing to a `Derived` would be:

```
std::shared_ptr<Base> BasePtr = std::make_shared<Derived>(42);
```

which directly constructs the `Derived` object with `42` passed to the constructor.

The dynamic cast applied to that would work.